# How to call google script api from my website?

Tags: google-api-php-client

I have created google script which returns a calculated number , how can i call it with parameter from my website and run the script and make it print on my website. ??

Comment: Have you tried Googling for it?  This is the first thing that came up for me https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api

Comment: yes i tried but m not getting the exact solution. can u help me?